How do I use primary keys of specialization as foreign key in a different table in MySQL?
I'm working on a Database project that handles employee information. The specialization of employees are maid, driver, and security guard. I decided to for a schema for each entity set with all local and inherited attributes. And since the specialization is total, I defined generalized entity set "employee" as a "view" relation containing the union of specialization relations. The problem I have is trying to create another table for employee phone number that uses emp_number as foreign key and (emp_number, phone_number) as primary key.
Here is what I have done so far:
CREATE TABLE maid(
  emp_number CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
  emp_name VARCHAR(2),
  address VARCHAR(50),
  birthday DATE
  experience_year INT);

CREATE TABLE driver(
  emp_number CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
  emp_name VARCHAR(2),
  address VARCHAR(50),
  birthday DATE
  license_number CHAR(6));

CREATE TABLE maid(
  emp_number CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
  emp_name VARCHAR(2),
  address VARCHAR(50),
  birthday DATE
  gun_license CHAR(6));

//Defining view of employee with general attributes
CREATE VIEW employee AS
SELECT 
    emp_number,
    emp_name,
    address,
    birthday,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURDATE()) AS age,
    'maid' AS employee_type
FROM 
    maid
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    emp_number,
    emp_name,
    address,
    birthday,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURDATE()) AS age,
    'driver' AS employee_type
FROM 
    driver
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    emp_number,
    emp_name,
    address,
    birthday,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURDATE()) AS age,
    'security_guard' AS employee_type
FROM 
    security_guard;

I tried using the employee view to create the table:
CREATE TABLE emp_phone (
    emp_number CHAR(8)NOT NULL,
    emp_phone CHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    number_type VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_number, emp_phone),
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_number) REFERENCES employee(emp_number)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

However, it gave me an error "Foreign Key Constraint is incorrectly formed. Upon research, I realized that you can't reference a view table.
Is there a better approach in referencing 'emp_number' for all specialization of employee?

There are multiple ways of modeling table inheritance. See Table Inheritance Design Strategies.

CREATE TABLE security_guard( ([mre])

Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

How can you represent inheritance in a database?
How do you effectively model inheritance in a database?
etc etc

Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Just have one table -- employee.  If some of the columns are optional, let them be NULLable.  Have a column for emp_type - maid, driver, etc.

You are mixing database design strategies for supertype - subtype modelling and this causes the problem.
First you decide to create completely separate tables for the 3 subtypes, even though 4 of their 5 columns are the same.
Then suddently, you want to store telephone numbers in a common table for all 3 entities. This is a different design strategy. Both strategies can be valid for your purposes, but mixing them is not a good idea.
Add the telephone number as separate column to the three subtype tables sticking with your current design strategy.
Alternatively, choose a different design strategy, but then redesign your current structure from scratch.
